# Is there way to ask even opinion based or non programming question but if it is useful for WordPress Developers?

Tags: discussion

Generally opinion based questions and most non programming question are off topic here. Is there way to ask even opinion based or non programming question but if it is useful for WordPress Developers.

---

**Example real question I have, which I like to ask WP SE**

> After working with WordPress a few years I have knowledge about how to
>   use CPT, CT, Meta Fields, etc.
>
> As a Web developer, the problem which I have is, I always try to do any
>   project with WordPress.
>
> **Ex 01** : A few months back I created a something like social network
>   for a client. I used WP with BuddyPress and some my custom code.
>
> **Ex 02**: I have build a social bookmarking site like Reddit. Again I used
>   WordPress for that also with some custom codes(front end login,posting,order CPT, etc).
>
> Even though how complex the requirements I always trying to do with
>   WordPress using some plugins and custom codes.
>
> I want to know that is it a good idea? Because of time saving (Sitemap
>   issues, SEO, Routing, etc take big time if I did not use WordPress) I
>   always go with WordPress how hard is requirements.
>
> Is it a good idea? Or how I decide I can't do this website with
>   WordPress. When should I avoid WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that opinion based questions are actually discussions, and this isn't a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site, you need to be able to mark an answer as **the answer, the concrete definitive answer**. That's not possible with those kinds of question.

Similarly recommending a plugin has the same problem. Stack Exchange terms them [shopping questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), where the answer the person might choose could be anything, and would be extremely specific to that person, at that particular time, making it not particularly useful to anybody else, or even the asker once a month or two has gone by.

The same is true of general discussions. Since the site isn't setup for extended discussion, and since we can have the same discussion over and over again, would it not be better to have those discussion on the .org forums/facebook groups/stack exchange chat/meetups/WordCamps/twitter/etc? Those locations are far better suited.